# Last 8 digits of nth term of morse thue

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

How to get the nth term of a Morse - thue sequence and what is the logic behind it??

I got the question find the last 8 digits of the  2008th term in a morse- thue sequence. What should I do ??

Comment: Did you look at OEIS sequence [A010060](http://oeis.org/A010060)?

Comment: Could not understand anything from It!!

Comment: What about the Wikipedia article [Morse-Thue sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence)?

Comment: "What should I do??"  Make a sincere attempt to understand what the question is asking and the reference material that is available to you.  Document your attempts and explain where you encounter difficulties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As phrased, it seems to be talking about the precursor terms to the Morse-Thue sequence:

$0$
$01$
$0110$
$01101001$
$0110100110010110$

You get each of these terms by appending the binary complement of the previous term to itself. So, once you have enough digits, the last eight digits just flip back & forth between complementary patterns of ones and zeroes.

Thus:
The last eight digits of the 2008$^{th}$ term in the sequence are the same as

- the last eight digits of the 2006$^{th}$ term
- the last eight digits of the 2004$^{th}$ term
  :
- the last eight digits of the 4$^{th}$ term

---

The Morse-Thue word itself is infinite, so has no "last 8 digits". The 8 digits in positions 2001 to 2008 can be determined by checking whether the binary representation of each contains an odd or an even count of the digit $1$. (The word starts with $0$ in position zero.)

$2008_{dec} = 11111011000_{bin}$ has $7$ instances of digit $1$ so the Morse-Thue digit is $1$.

The preceding $7$ position values of interest differ only in the last $4$ binary digits so are easy to calculate by difference from the above.